# Please help on the foursquare and heroku API using python

Tags: python, heroku, foursquare

This is my code:

```
    app.route('/search/',methods=['GET'])
    def search():
        lat = request.args.get(lat)
        lng = request.args.get(lng)`
        amenity = request.args.get(amenity)
        params='ll',str(lat) + ',' + str(lng)+str(amenity)
        client =foursquare.Foursquare(client_id='',client_secret='')
        return jsonify(message=client.venues.search(params))
```

when i execute it it runs and when i push it to heroku and try to search ising my lat and lng it shows internal server error....

http://drut1.herokuapp.com/search/?lat=51&lng=-3&amenity=coffee

where am i going wrong? is it code?

Comment: 1. Can you format your code better so it's easier to read? 2. Please provide us with any output python gives you so it's easier to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all you got some syntax errors in your code.

```
app.route('/search/',methods=['GET'])
```

should be:

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET'])
```

and:

```
lat = request.args.get(lat)
```

should be

```
lat = request.args.get('lat')
```

I tested your code locally without the foursquare part and it works like expected.

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET'])
def search():
    lat = request.args.get('lat')
    lng = request.args.get('lng')
    amenity = request.args.get('amenity')
    params='ll',str(lat) + ',' + str(lng)+str(amenity)
    #client =foursquare.Foursquare(client_id='',client_secret='')
    #return jsonify(message=client.venues.search(params))
    return 'OK'
```